# Is developer edition turn by default after expire of Enterprise trial edition?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using Coldfusion 9 Enterprise trial edition which will expire in 30 days of installation. I want to know after expire of trail version which will turn into Developer edition by default? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

> The Trial Edition is fully functional and intended for simulated production and evaluation purposes only. It contains all of the Enterprise Edition features and will timeout after 30 days from the time you install the product. After the timeout period, the Trial Edition will revert to the Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know the Developer Edition also has all the features of Enterprise (I believe) with the exception of limiting only 2 or 3 connections to the server.